# AppDelegate Touch3D Xcode - TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, touch

I'm trying to implement 3D Touch in xcode 7.3.1 in swift 2 for the first time. I inserted the information in info.plist, up to here works as you can see from code to open the view works, the problem is that I do not view the TabBar ... so I decided to change everything, open the tab controller, and then move from there type in the section with selectindex = 2, but do not know how to do ... the select index function AppDelegate with work, someone can help me?

This is my code in AppDelegate to manage 3D Touch

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: Bool -> Void) {
        //questo codice verrà eseguito ogni volta che le Quick Actions verranno eseguite
        if (shortcutItem.type == "com.tuu.openSearch") {
          //section search THIS WORK without TabBar!!
            let viewcontroller = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchID")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewcontroller, animated: false, completion: nil)
            })

        }
        if (shortcutItem.type == "com.tuu.openFavorite"){
            //section tabbar favorite, self.tabBarcontroller.selectedIndex = 2 not work!!
            let viewcontroller = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("favoritesID")
            viewcontroller.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewcontroller, animated: false, completion: nil)

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please let me know whether viewController is UIViewController or UINavgitaionController?

Comment: this is TabController, This was in fact error... thank's, now works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
if (shortcutItem.type == "com.tuu.openFavorite"){
            let tabBarController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("favoritesID") as! UITabBarController
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
            self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController

        }
```